# Python itertools permutation MemoryError

Tags: python, permutation, gurobi

I'm running a permutation on a list with len(list)=20. The total result possible cases are 2432902008176640000. That is (20!)20 factorial. This is so big that it exceeds the list maxMemory size. Any solution?

```
perms = list(itertools.permutations('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP', r=20))
```

Comment: The idea behind using itertools is that you don't need to put everything in memory. That advantage goes away when you try to store it in a `list()`. What are you trying to do with all these permutations? Spending a 1/10 of a millisecond on each one will still take several million years.

Comment: Why do you need all 20! permutations in memory at once?  That defeats the usual purpose of using the `permutations` generator.  We can't suggest a solution when we don't know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: yes, don't create a list of all permutations.

Comment: What did you plan on *doing* with the list? If you want a random sample of the permutations, you can instead pass a random *shuffling* of the letters to `permutations`; that will essentially give you a random sequence of permutation, from which you can just take a prefix of the desired size.